# How to install tkinter or Tcl for python 2.7 on windows 7?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am getting following errors. When I am searching on web I am not able to understand how to do that.Following program I am running please help.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
from Tkinter import *

tweets_data_path = 'C:/Users/e2sn7cy/Documents/GitHub/twitter_data.txt'

tweets_data = []

tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, 'r')

for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
    except:
        continue
    if not all([x in tweet for x in ['text', 'lang', 'place']]):
        continue
    if tweet['place'] and not 'country' in tweet['place']:
        continue
    tweets_data.append(tweet)

#print len(tweets_data)

#DataFrame
tweets = pd.DataFrame()

#adding columns

tweets['text'] = map(lambda tweet:tweet['text'] if tweet['text'] else '', tweets_data)

#tweets['text'] = [tweet['text'] for tweet in tweets_data]

tweets['lang'] = map(lambda tweet:tweet['lang'] if tweet['lang'] else '', tweets_data)

#tweets['lang'] = [tweet['lang'] for tweet in tweets_data]

tweets['country'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['country'] if tweet['place'] != None else None, tweets_data)

#Adding Charts
tweets_by_lang = tweets['lang'].value_counts()

#pd.value_counts(tweets.values.flatten())

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=15)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=10)
ax.set_xlabel('Languages', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Number of tweets' , fontsize=15)
ax.set_title('Top 5 languages', fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
tweets_by_lang[:5].plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', color='red')
```

Error:

```
(venv) c:\Users\e2sn7cy\Documents\GitHub\Twitter-App>python twitter_analytics.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter_analytics.py", line 46, in <module>
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  File "C:\myPython\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 1078, in subplots
    fig = figure(**fig_kw)
  File "C:\myPython\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 435, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\myPython\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 81, in new_fig
ure_manager
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
  File "C:\myPython\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 89, in new_fig
ure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1810, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync,
 use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
    C:/Python27/lib/tcl8.5 C:/myPython/venv/lib/tcl8.5 C:/myPython/lib/tcl8.5 C:/myPython/venv/librar
y C:/myPython/library C:/myPython/tcl8.5.15/library C:/tcl8.5.15/library



This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

I tried online search, i searched stackoverflow but I am not able to understand what should i install please Help. I have already downloaded the tcl8.5.15-src.tar.gz file. But I am not able to install this file as no setup.py is there.

Comment: `Tcl wasn't installed properly` Isn't that the key ?

Comment: My advice: install ActivePython from ActiveState. It's the easiest, most painless way to install Python on Windows IMHO.

Comment: When you install Python make sure it also installes Tk for the Tkinter module. AFAIK the box for that is checked by default in the installer(s) from python.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated my Python to 2.7.10 and I have also set the check marks over TCL line and now I am not getting that error.